# Confused with Data.Data.toConstr

Tags: haskell

I'm confused why for given data type

```
import Data.Data
data T a = T1 a | T2 deriving Data
```

the expression

```
toConstr (Just ()) == toConstr (T2 :: T Int)
```

returns `True`, while

```
toConstr (Just ()) == toConstr (T1 ())
```

returns `False`.

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431770/custom-generic-representation-of-the-data-type)

Comment: You should ask your edit as a new question - more people will see that you've asked something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Constr) -

> Note that equality on constructors with different types may not work -- i.e. the constructors for False and Nothing may compare equal.

`Just ()` is a constructor of `Maybe ()` - it won't necessarily compare false to the constructors of `T`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I determine whether value is `Just` something or `Nothing` using `Data`/`Typeable`?

Comment: Comparison between `Just` and `Nothing` should still work, as they have the same type. If you're having problems with that, ask in a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my question where I described how I came to this question.