# Custom generic representation of the data type

Tags: haskell

I need to generically render an html form by the given record type. For this reason, I've created type class

```
class EntityRep a where
  toRep :: Proxy a -> [FieldRep]
  default toRep :: (Generic a, GEntityRep (Rep a)) => Proxy a -> [FieldRep]
  toRep _ = gtoRep (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep a))
```

where

```
data FieldRep = FieldRep
  { fieldName :: String
  , fieldRequired :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)
class GEntityRep f where
  gtoRep :: Proxy f -> [FieldRep]
```

And the instance for the selector representation:

```
instance (Selector a, Required a) => GEntityRep (M1 S s (K1 R a)) where
  gtoRep _ = [FieldRep { fieldName = selName (undefined :: M1 S s (K1 R a) ())
                       , fieldRequired = isRequired (Proxy @a) }]
```

So I want to implement the function

```
isRequired :: (Required a) => Proxy a -> Bool
--returns True, only if the type is (Maybe a) for all a
```

My attempt was to use `Data.Data`:

```
constrs :: forall a. (Data a) => Proxy a -> [Constr]
constrs _ = let dt = dataTypeOf (undefined :: a)
  in if isAlgType dt then dataTypeConstrs dt
     else []
isRequired :: forall a. (Data a) => Proxy a -> Bool
isRequired proxy =
     toConstr (Nothing :: Maybe ()) `elem` (constrs proxy)
  || toConstr (Just () :: Maybe ()) `elem` (constrs proxy)
```

But this does not work, because constrs for different types may be equal.

At the end, for the following record

```
data PK a = PK a | Unset deriving (Data, Typeable, Show)
data ProductCategory = Clothes | Food deriving (Data, Typeable, Show)
data Product = Product { productName :: String
                       , productCategory :: ProductCategory
                       , productPrice :: Maybe Int } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance EntityRep Product
```

the following expression

```
>>> toRep (Proxy @Product)
```

should return

```
[FieldRep{fieldName="productName"
         ,fieldRequired=True}
,FieldRep{fieldName="productCategory"
         ,fieldRequired=True}
,FieldRep{fieldName="productPrice"
         ,fieldRequired=False}]
```

I could create the type class

```
class Required a where
  isRequired :: Proxy a -> Bool
```

then implement it for the various of types, but it's so bothersome. And all instances will be identical, except `Maybe a`.

### Edit. Using overlapping instances

We can make a default implementation

```
instance Required a where
  isRequired _ = True
```

then overlap it with the `Maybe a` instance:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Required (Maybe a) where
  isRequired _ = False
```

Comment: I suspect this might be easier to do with `Generic` and overlapping instances (you'd have overlapping instances for `PK` and `Maybe` fields).

Comment: It's pretty hard to read your draft code and work out what you're *actually* trying to accomplish. Could you please edit your question to explain the problem in much more detail before you get to your draft solution? There are already some minor red flags, like the combination of `Generic` with `Data`, but I don't even want to think about a solution because I don't feel like I understand the problem yet.

Comment: `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` does the trick. Thanks

Comment: By the way: there's a [usefull technique](http://brandon.si/code/how-the-haskell-prelude-avoids-overlapping-types-in-show/) to avoid overlapping instances. But it seems that this trick is not applicable in my case

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the [approach](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-02-05-avoid-overlapping-instances-with-closed-type-families.html), using `TypeFamilies`

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Proxy

type family (F a) :: Bool where
  F (Maybe a) = 'False
  F a = 'True

class Required a where
  isRequired :: Proxy a -> Bool

class Required' (flag :: Bool) a where
  isRequired' :: Proxy flag -> Proxy a -> Bool

instance (F a ~ flag, Required' flag a) => Required a where
  isRequired = isRequired' (Proxy :: Proxy flag)

instance Required' 'False (Maybe a) where
  isRequired' _ _ = False

instance Required' 'True a where
  isRequired' _ x = True
```